# Google App Scripts Error Notification on Non-Existent Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

How do I turn off alerts that I keep getting for a script that doesn't exist anymore? I created a google apps script to monitor a gmail account, but it didn't work right and I deleted the script. I currently have zero scripts associates with my account, but I still get this email every day:

*Your script, Gmail Meter, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.
Details:
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End
1/28/15 1:16 AM activityReport  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  1/28/15 1:16 AM
Sincerely,
Google Apps Script*

There's a link to change seettings, but when I click the link I get a "Forbidden - Error 403" page (probably because the script isn't there anymore). It's super annoying anyone know of a way to turn of the alert that is causing this message?

Answer (score 3):

I found this worked after getting script errors caused by 'Gmail Meter' which is an app I installed from the Chrome Web Store.

Go to [script.google.com](https://script.google.com/) . If you were like me and have never been here before click the blue "Start Scripting" button.

Go to "Edit" menu -> "All your triggers".

A dialogue should pop up prompting you to save the current script. Rename to Temp and Click Ok.

Try to find the trigger that's sending the email and delete it. Or if you are like me, just delete whatever is there (which was only one line) by clicking the small gray 'x' at the start of the line.

Now it should state "No triggers set up. Click here to add one now."

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

This is interesting, it sounds like the Trigger is still running despite the script being removed.

Try creating an empty script, then select "All your triggers" from the "Edit" menu.  You will be prompted to give your empty script a name, so call it "temp" or something along those lines.

Once the "All your triggers" window opens, hopefully you will see the trigger that's generating the error and be able to delete it by clicking the X.

Once finished you can delete your temp script.