# Stopping Google EML emails that are have been and will be sent for every, every few minutes

Tags: android

I  RECEIVE THIS EMAIL EVERY MULTIPLE TIMER PER DAY FROM  Google Apps Script.

Email subject:

Your script, the Eml Manager, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.

mail content:

Error Message   Count 48
Authorization is required to perform that action.
Start   Function    Error Message   Trigger End

THE REPORT THEN LISTS 48 INSTANCES OF FAILURE, ONE GENERATED EVERY 30 MINUTES

```
2/17/18 10:12 PM    garbageCollectorViewer  Authorization is required to perform that action.   time-based  2/17/18 10:12 PM
2/17/18 10:42 PM    garbageCollectorViewer  Authorization is r
```

I AM INNOCENT GMAIL USER. I DO NOT KNOW WHAT THIS IS ABOUT. I AM CONCERNED THAT THIS PROCESS WILL KEEP RUNNING AFTER I DIE, WASTING ENERGY IN MAINTAINING THIS PROCESS.

IS THERE ANYTHING THAT CAN BE DONE TO STOP THIS?

THANK YOU,

I entered ANDROID as "tag" below because it was the only word that I recognized...

Comment: I think there is a similar question already, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28198531/google-app-scripts-error-notification-on-non-existent-script

Answer (score 2):

Answer found on EML Manager support page. Tested & verified!

1. Go with your account to the following link:
   https://script.google.com/d/1YFLzT9QQUQbothW5dY8w8SU28DYRZ7HOBwUIPPLt4lyESLdPdm_MG2nd/edit?usp=sharing
2. Under Edit, click on "all your triggers"
3. A pop-up is opened. Click the X button to the left of
   "garbageCollectorViewer" and than click on the Save button (see image
   below)
4. Close everything & you're done

Hope this helps someone else as it drove me crazy for agessss!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://script.google.com/home/triggers and remove them with right click and then "delete".